# Rails Routes broken in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After sailing along for years in development, including deploying on Heroku, I'm following Ryan Bates's Railscast for deploying to a VPS (Linode) for staging. Everything deploys smoothly, unicorn starts up, then throws an error on any route I request, viz (this for a simple pages#welcome request):

```
Started GET "/welcome" for 108.74.161.183 at 2014-09-15 22:02:43 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/welcome"):
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:573:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:667:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:522:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:533:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:291:in `join'
  unicorn (4.8.2) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/RP/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /var/www/RP/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'



***** Debugger requested, but was not available (ensure the debugger gem is listed in Gemfile/installed as gem): Start server with --debugger to enable *****
```

Performance is identical whether I start up unicorn or unicorn_rails. And when I run 'rake routes' on the server, it dutifully lists all the routes it should. Besides the routes failure, the one thing I don't understand is the lines about debugger requests. There ARE no debugger calls in my code, either in /app or /lib. But I don't see any connection between a debugger warning (which has never been a problem before) and routing failures.

I'm sitting here tearing my hair out because I can't imagine what could be the source of this problem. Huge thanks in advance for any productive suggestion.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0' # '3.2.11' #
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
# gem 'rails4_upgrade'
gem 'rails_12factor', :group => [ :production, :staging ]

# add these gems to help with the transition:
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'  
# gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
# gem 'actionpack-action_caching'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:

gem 'pg'

gem 'builder', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'draper', '~> 1.3'
gem 'closure_tree'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'nokogiri', "~> 1.5" # "~> 1.5.3"
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.1.0'                       # auth, rails generate devise:install, rails generate devise MODEL
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.3.0' # git: 'git://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git'
gem 'ruby-openid'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'                      
gem 'omniauth-facebook' # , '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'                     
gem 'omniauth-openid'                     
gem 'declarative_authorization'     # simple auth rules/roles, create config/authorization_rules.rb, add filter_resource_access to each controller, use permitted_to? in views
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.3'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem "rmagick", "~> 2.13.2"
gem "feedzirra", "~> 0.2" # :git => 'git://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git'
gem "simple_form", :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git' # , '~> 3.0.0.beta1' 
gem 'delayed_job' # , git: 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record' # , git: 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record.git'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'hirefire-resource'
# gem 'debugger', :group => [:test, :development]
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'content_for_in_controllers'
gem 'youtube_addy'
# gem 'active_model_serializers'

gem 'exception_notification', git: 'git://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification.git'
# gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.1', :require => 'exception_notifier' # , git: 'git://github.com/alanjds/exception_notification.git' 
group :development do
  gem 'minitest', '~> 4.2'
  # gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
  gem "nifty-generators"
  gem 'log_buddy'
  gem 'ruby-prof', '~> 0.13.0' # , :git => 'git://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  # gem "json"
end

gem "masonry-rails"

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails', "~> 1.0" # gem 'minitest', '~> 4.2'
  # gem 'rspec-rails'
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'webrat', '~> 0.7.3'
  gem "minitest-rails-capybara" # ...for simulating user interaction
  # gem "guard-rspec" # ...for auto-running tests on file save
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.0"
  gem "mocha"
  gem 'poltergeist'
end

gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 4.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0' # '~> 3.1.1'
# gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'unicorn-rails'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'sshkit', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
# gem 'capistrano-rvm'
```

Routes.rb:

```
  unless @RPRoutesLoaded
    @RPRoutesLoaded = true

    RP::Application.routes.draw do

      if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
        # IntegersController is for testing streams
        get "integers" => 'integers#index'
      end
      resources :votes, :only => :create
      post '/votes/recipes/:recipe_id' => 'votes#create', :as => "vote_recipe"
      get 'pic_picker/new' => 'pic_picker#new'

      get "redirect/go"
      get '/auth/failure' => 'authentications#failure'
      # get '/authentications/new' => 'authentications#new'
      resources :authentications

      devise_for :users, :skip => [ :registrations ], :controllers => {
          :sessions => 'sessions',
          :passwords => 'passwords',
          :invitations => 'invitations',
          # :registrations => 'registrations' # Had to elide this and use devise_scope to define /users/register instead of /users to create
      }

      match 'users', :controller=>'users', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      devise_scope :user do
        post "/users/register" => "registrations#create", :as => "user_registration"
        get "/users/sign_up" => "registrations#new", :as => "new_user_registration"
        get "/users/edit" => "registrations#edit", :as => "edit_user_registration"
        get "/users/cancel" => "registrations#cancel", :as => "cancel_user_registration"
        put "/users" => "registrations#update"
        delete "/users" => "registrations#destroy"
        get "/users/sign_out" => "sessions#destroy"
        patch "/users" => "registrations#update"

        get "/users/invitation/divert" => "invitations#divert", :as => "divert_user_invitation"
      end

      get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
      post '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

      # Calling 'profile' action in 'users' controller edits the current user
      get 'users/profile' => 'users#profile'
      # Ask a user to identify him/herself by email address
      get 'users/identify' => 'users#identify'
      get 'users/:id/recent' => 'users#recent'
      get 'users/:id/collection' => 'users#collection'
      get 'users/:id/biglist' => 'users#biglist'
      # get 'users/:id/show' => 'users#show'
      resources :users, :except => [ :index, :create ] do
        member do
          get 'collect'
          post 'remove'
          get 'match_friends'
          get 'notify'
          get 'acquire' # Acquire a recipe (etc.)
        end
      end

      post '/list' => 'lists#create', :as => 'create_list'
      resources :lists, except: [ :index, :create ] do
        member do
          get 'scrape'
        end
      end
      match 'lists', :controller=>'lists', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      post '/site' => 'sites#create', :as => 'create_site'
      resources :sites, except: [ :index, :create ] do
        member do
          get 'scrape'
        end
      end
      match 'sites', :controller=>'sites', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      post '/reference' => 'references#create', :as => 'create_reference'
      resources :references, :except => [ :index, :create ]
      match 'references', :controller=>'references', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      post '/feed' => 'feeds#create', :as => 'create_feed'
      resources :feeds, :except => [ :index, :create ] do
        member do
          get 'collect' # Add the feed to the current user
          post 'remove' # Remove the feed from the current user's set
          post 'approve' # (Admin only) approve the feed for presentation
        end
      end
      match 'feeds', :controller=>'feeds', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      post '/tag' => 'tags#create', :as => 'create_tag'
      resources :tags, except: [ :index, :create ] do
        member do
          post 'absorb'
        end
        collection do
          get 'editor'
          get 'list'
          get 'typify'
          get 'match'
        end
      end
      match 'tags', :controller=>'tags', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]

      match 'collection', :controller=>'collection', :action=>'index', :via => [:get, :post]
      post 'collection/update'
      get "collection/refresh"
      get "collection/feed"
      get "collection/show", as: 'collection_show'
      get "collection/new"
      get "collection/edit"
      post "collection/create"
      get "collection/relist"

      get "stream/stream"
      get "stream/buffer_test"
      get "iframe/create"
      get "admin/data"
      get "admin/control"
      get "notifications/accept"

      resources :thumbnails
      resources :feedback, :only => [:new, :create]
      resources :expressions
      resources :referents
      resources :ratings
      resources :scales

      resources :recipes do
        resources :tags do
          member { post 'remove', :to => 'recipes#untag' }
        end
        member do
          get 'collect'
          get 'touch'
          get 'piclist'
          post 'remove'
        end
        collection do
          get 'capture'
          post 'parse'
        end
      end
      get '/revise', :to => 'recipes#revise'

      # get "pages/home"
      # get "pages/contact"
      # get "pages/about"
      get '/home', :to => 'pages#home'
      get '/popup/:name', :to => 'pages#popup'
      get '/popup', :to => 'pages#popup'
      get '/share', :to => 'pages#share'
      get '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
      get '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
      get '/welcome', :to => 'pages#welcome'
      get '/faq', :to=>"pages#faq"
      get '/admin', :to=>"pages#admin"
      get '/mobi', :to=>"pages#mobi"
      root :to => 'pages#root'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just for kicks, can you add your Gemfile?

Comment: Does your index page work okay?

Comment: `routes.rb`? Could be helpful.

Comment: No pages work at all. (routes file added)

Comment: What development server and production server are you using? Are they the same?

Comment: I'm using unicorn for both development and staging, though the former is on OS X and the latter on Ubuntu (production on Heroku under Linux (?) is also fine). The suspicious thing is that on OS X all my gems (installed with rvm) are under gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286, but on Ubuntu (installed with rbenv), they're under ruby/1.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer: it seems that long ago I attempted to memoize the loading of routes by using a flag to prevent executing the load code in routes.rb more than once. For some reason Rails decided to reload them twice in the life of that flag, with the result that the second load was blocked, resulting in...no routes! It wasn't a question of platform but of environment, staging being the only victim environment. I don't know why routes were getting reloaded in staging but not in development or production, but that was the source of the problem.